# How to find ingress and egress traffic of a particular GCP VM machine?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, network-traffic

I have a VM which has only Internal IP. How can I find the ingress and egress of that particular VM machine ? Could anyone please help me with this.

Comment: Your question does not provide details on what you want to capture. @dany-l provides a good answer with the available options. Be careful, capturing raw traffic can be expensive. If possible, use a capture tool inside the instance and analyze there which is almost free. If you must capture from outside the instance, VPC flow logs are an excellent option (about $0.50/GB).

Answer (score 5):

If you want to analyze everything live, you can do a [packet capture and investigate in wireshark](https://www.varonis.com/blog/packet-capture/).

If you want to investigate from a graph stand point try this:

```
Menu > Monitoring > Dashboards > VM instances > Network Tab > ....
```

If you want to analyze from Logging stand point, please check [VPC flow logs](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-flow-logs).

If you want to analyze from a billing perspective, check [this](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/network-pricing).